# Jquery - 2 Ajax request dont work on the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So I have Had this problem for a day a and i am unable to send 2 ajax requests from the same page.
Most of the documentation i have read is about running 2 versions of jquery on the same page with the **no conflict method**
But i am trying to send 2 ajax requests, with the same version of Jquery.

Heres my code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var username = $("title").html();
    $.post("functions/userdetails.php", {username: username},
    function(result){
      if(result == 'nf'){
          alert("The Account Doesnt Exist");
      }
      else{
          var obj = JSON.parse(result);
          $.each(obj, function(key, val) {          // iterate over results
          $("#name").html(val.fname+" "+val.lname);
          $("#bio").html(val.bio);
          $("#username").html("@"+val.username);
          $("#tid").html(val.id);
        })        
    }
    }
);
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    var tid = $("tid").html();
    var myid = $("myid").html();
    $.post("functions/checkrelations.php", {tid: tid, myid:myid},
    function(result){
      if(result == 'nf'){
          $("#sendr").show();
          $("#cancel").hide();
      }
      else{
          $("#cancel").show();
          $("#sendr").hide();
        })        
    }
    }
);
});
</script>
```

It works well if i only have one request, but when i put these together, none of them work.

Comment: Your second docReady uses the string `"document"` instead of the object `document`

Comment: My Bad. I've edited the code and still doesnt work..
I havent seen any code using multiple queries .. do they work normally?

Comment: Why do you use twice $(document).ready method... Only once is sufficient, then run your two ajax calls...

Comment: Ajax is asynchronous , so both of these ajax executes at same time, but you are taking html values to make the second ajax ,but these values are not yet created because the first ajax is not completed yet

Comment: There are some additional errors in your second docReady. `$("tid")` should probably be `$("#tid")`. Also, there's an incorrectly matched closing parenthesis after the `else` block.

Comment: The Problem has been solved. the main error as @AnanthakrishnanBaji said was that my second request depended on my first. 
Thanks.

Comment: Thanks my friend, please close the question and give the other guy (Sam) answer an upvote

Comment: Yes i did upvote his answer.Though it is not very clear how i shd close it.
they have said i should close it if it is unhelpful, not abt programming etc..
Where is the ' Solved ' option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the edited version of your code, this may help you

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var username = $("title").html();
        $.post("functions/userdetails.php", {username: username},
        function(result){
          if(result == 'nf'){
              alert("The Account Doesnt Exist");
          }
          else{
                  var obj = JSON.parse(result);
                  $.each(obj, function(key, val) {          // iterate over results
                  $("#name").html(val.fname+" "+val.lname);
                  $("#bio").html(val.bio);
                  $("#username").html("@"+val.username);
                  $("#tid").html(val.id);
                });

                //here is the first ajax calls completes succesfully and your 
                //new html is build so second ajax must be called from here

                    var tid = $("#tid").html();
                    var myid = $("#myid").html();
                    $.post("functions/checkrelations.php", {tid: tid, myid:myid},
                    function(result){
                          if(result == 'nf'){
                              $("#sendr").show();
                              $("#cancel").hide();
                          }
                          else{
                              $("#cancel").show();
                              $("#sendr").hide();
                            }       
                        }               
                );
           }
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: had to make few small mods. but it worked like a charm.
Thanks

Comment: So can u please accept the answer and close the question, Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As Ananthakrishnan Baji said in a comment, it appears your second function depends on your first function.

There are a couple of additional issues with the second function. The IDs are missing the hash mark in the jQuery selectors. The closing parenthesis for the function seems to be caught up at the else statement.

Rather than just nest the functions and end up deep into a nested block of code, I recommend using Promises to keep the code depth low and also handle your errors. Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var username = $("title").html();
    // Make your first request
    $.post("functions/userdetails.php", {username: username})
    // Handle the first response
    .then(function(result) {
        if (result === 'nf') {
            // Use promise chain rejection to handle errors.
            return $.Deferred().reject("The Account Doesn't Exist");
        } else {
            var obj = JSON.parse(result);
            // Are there actually multiple, here?
            // This will overwrite on each loop.
            $.each(obj, function(key, val) {          
                $("#name").html(val.fname + " " + val.lname);
                $("#bio").html(val.bio);
                $("#username").html("@" + val.username);
                $("#tid").html(val.id);
            });
        }
    })
    // Make the next request.
    .then(function() {
        var tid = $("#tid").html();
        var myid = $("#myid").html();
        return $.post("functions/checkrelations.php", {tid: tid, myid:myid});
    })
    // Update the appearance
    .then(function(result) {
        if (result === 'nf') {
            $("#sendr").show();
            $("#cancel").hide();
        } else {
            $("#cancel").show();
            $("#sendr").hide();
        }
    })
    // This is the "catch" logic.
    .then(null, function(errorMessage) {
        if (typeof errorMessage === 'string') {
            alert(errorMessage);
        } else {
            // If the requests error, or the JSON.parse throws, we end up here.
            alert('Something went wrong!');
        }
    }
});
```